# Neo4j stream through Java driver is slower than Neo4j desktop

Tags: java, neo4j

Im running a Neo4j docker in my local and trying to access via Java driver and neo4j desktop. I understand that results are streamed after the execution.

I get a difference in completion time between neo4j desktop and java driver. The former completes in 18 ms where as later takes 220 ms for the same query. Am I missing anything to configure in Java driver(4.1.1)

Please note that the response time doesn't include the session time and its not a first query. I understand that for the first query execution takes bit longer than subsequent queries

Comment: did you warm-up the java driver or was its first query? Try running 100 querys and see the result later

Comment: It was not a first query, Also I didn't include the session time

Answer (score 1):

In the Neo4j browser, the `Driver` object is already instantiated after logging in, which means that the only object used ( and for which the time is representative ), it the time a Session takes to execute a transaction.

The `Driver` object instantiation in the Java driver is the *slowest* one, so you should really measure only the Session time to run the transaction.

Comment: Please note that the response time doesn't include to get the session and its not a first query